# not able to include double quotes in string using java

Tags: java, json

I am stuck in formatting my `String` value to be used as `JSONObject`. After consuming client side API I am getting below response:

```
{
 "apiKey": "537563615208489705083657373",
 "data": "{\"Apparent Power kVA\":14.4,\"Grid Duration\":7990260,\"Grid MD kW\":0.59,\"Grid MD kVA\":0.59,\"Voltage\":240,\"Device Sr.No.\":\"SMR01-4417-0002\",\"Frequency\":49.94,\"Remaining Balance\":2737.35,\"Load Relay Status\":\"Connected\",\"Timestamp\":\"2018-02-26 18:31:18\",\"Current\":60,\"Active Power kW\":14.4}"
}
```

I put that in my String literal. But as you can see, the response has keys with spaces. It also has backslashes(\).

So I used below code to overcome this problem:

```
        abc= abc.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        abc=abc.replaceAll("\"", "");
        abc=abc.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

and now I am getting below output of `abc`:

```
{
apiKey:537563615208489705083657373,
data:{ApparentPowerkVA:14.4,GridDuration:7990260,GridMDkW:0.59,GridMDkVA:0.59,Voltage:240,DeviceSr.No.:SMR01-4417-0002,Frequency:49.94,RemainingBalance:2737.35,LoadRelayStatus:Connected,Timestamp:2018-02-2618:31:18,Current:60,ActivePowerkW:14.4}
}
```

I successfully removed all nonsense characters. But I needed double quotes to be able to put `abc` in `org.JSONObject` constructor. But I am not able to do so. Can any one help me out.

Comment: If you have the value of `data` as a String, you need to have those escaped. Why are you unescaping it?

Comment: Use `abc=abc.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");` instead of `abc=abc.replaceAll("\"", "");`

Comment: If you parse the outer object, you should be able to parse the value of the data field as normal json

Comment: Your `String` has `"\""` because you have a JSON with a`data` holding a `String`,  not an object. The generation is incorrect.

Comment: You are supposed to parse this string as json as-is, then get the "data" key and parse that value as json. Do not modify either string. Do not replace quotes or backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your String in the property data is absolutely fine to be interpreted as Java String. With the following code:

`String data = "{\"Apparent Power kVA\":14.4, ...";
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);`

I get this output:

`{
 "Apparent Power kVA": 14.4,
 "Grid Duration": 7990260,
 "Grid MD kW": 0.59,
 "Grid MD kVA": 0.59,
 "Voltage": 240,
 "Device Sr.No.": "SMR01-4417-0002",
 "Frequency": 49.94,
 "Remaining Balance": 2737.35,
 "Load Relay Status": "Connected",
 "Timestamp": "2018-02-26 18:31:18",
 "Current": 60,
 "Active Power kW": 14.4
}`

Tested with [JSON Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) v20180130

Comment: Could you test with the full JSON ? `data` is not an object in the question, but a `String`, so it shuold not output like your example (unless I misread)

Comment: If you need the whole thing then all those quotes arround apiKey, data, .. have to be escaped to. Howerever, this depends on how you get your input. I am currently just writing the String direcly down in the code, which propably isn't the case in @JPG 's question.

Answer (score 0):

as `@O.O. Balance` caught my mistake, I made a following method which successfully creates `org.JSONObject` and returns it as String.

```
private static String getCorrectFormat(String original) throws JSONException {
        original= original.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        original=original.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
        original=original.replaceAll(" ", "");

        original=original.replace("\"data\":\"", "\"data\":");
        original = original.replace("}\"", "}");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(original);
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

Thank you @O.O. Balance

Comment: here `data` is fixed. Its sure that it gonna come.